# Color profile from calibration affects Windows' Preview

Tags: color-management, windows, color-spaces

I recently bought an [X-Rite i1 Display Pro](http://www.xrite.com/i1display-pro) that I used to calibrate my notebook. I [had some problems](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60854/x-rite-i1-display-pro-settings-for-a-notebook) with the calibration, but it turned out that my settings were not perfect and in the end I managed to achieve a good calibration. I'm mentioning this because the following problem might be about calibration settings too (I can't find a solution though).

Every time my notebook loads Windows 8, there is a process that automatically load the ICC profile I saved during the calibration, which sets up the correct colors. When I start to work with my calibrated screen and open a picture with "Windows Preview", the picture is eventually displayed with an insane amount of contrast. If I click onto "full screen" it would then show the same picture with totally wrong colors.
If I use Lightroom or Photoshop to open that very picture, the colors are correct and I also found out that if I softproof the image using different profiles, the results are equal to those shown in "Windows Preview".

As background you should know that I am using a notebook with a dedicated graphic card (and its own control panel), but I am currently letting Windows overtake all the color correction settings (there is also an option to let the graphic card control panel do that).

I also found out that in Windows' control panel there is an option to manage ICC profiles, but I couldn't find a way to set correctly.

Could you guys please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Windows doesn't manage ICC profiles created with version 4, so I'd have to use version 2 while calibrating.

Source: X-Rite support

[How not to make Windows display false colors](http://www.davegoldmanphotography.com/blog/2014/2/win-7-8-and-8-1-incompatability-issues-with-windows-photo-viewer-and-v4-icc-profiles)

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop and Lightroom are color-managed software tools while the windows preview isn't.

If you're doing softproof with any type of profile, it's normal that it appears strange. Softproofing is only to see how the prints will come out.

Check out the eBook to get knowledge about the whole workflow of digital color management:
http://spyder.datacolor.com/scripts/ebook-en/Spyder_eBook_EN_final.pdf

Comment: The first sentence partially replies to my question, but please notice that I did not ask about softproof. I would only like to know how can I set windows to be color-managed too...